# How to compare the login credentials given by the user to the salt and hash stored in your database to permit user login

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, cryptography, salt

I have done some research online and watched some YouTube videos and piece together a code to salt the password and then hash the salted password and store both the salt and the hash into the database.
Right now, I'm currently stuck on how to compare the password given by the user to the salt stored in the database.

I do not know where to go on from here, and I could really use some guide and help.
Although i did try manually taking the salt and comparing it to the verifyPassword. But it does not work. I believe I lack some understanding in the code.

**USER REGISTRATION PAGE**

```
public class HashSalt
    {
        public string Hash { get; set; }
        public string Salt { get; set; }
    }

    public static HashSalt GenerateSaltedHash(int size, string password)
    {
        var saltBytes = new byte[size];
        var provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        provider.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);
        var salt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);

        var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, 10000);
        var hashPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256));

        HashSalt hashSalt = new HashSalt { Hash = hashPassword, Salt = salt };
        return hashSalt;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HashSalt hashSalt = GenerateSaltedHash(64, txtPassConfirm.Text);
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Customer values (@FirstName, @LastName, @Nationality, @Email, @Tel);" +
                "insert into Account values(@Email2, @Salt, @Hash);", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", txtLName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nationality", ddlNationality.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", txtMail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tel", txtTel.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email2", txtMail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salt", hashSalt.Salt);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash", hashSalt.Hash);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Number == 2627)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }


        txtFName.Text = "";
        txtLName.Text = "";
        ddlNationality.SelectedItem.Text = "";
        txtTel.Text = "";
        txtMail.Text = "";

        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
```

**USER LOGIN PAGE**

```
public static bool VerifyPassword(string enteredPassword, string storedHash, string storedSalt)
    {
        var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(storedSalt);
        var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(enteredPassword, saltBytes, 10000);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256)) == storedHash;
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        string CommandText = "SELECT FirstName from Customer" + "SELECT Email, Salt, Hash from Account";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, myConnect);
        myConnect.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader["Email"].ToString() == txtMail.Text )
            {
                bool isPasswordMatched = VerifyPassword(txtPass.Text,)
                Session["User"] = reader["FirstName"].ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                lblResult.Text = "Incorrect Username or Password, Please Try Again!";
            }
        }
    }
```

**Database Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account] (
    [EMail] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Salt]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Hash]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EMail] ASC)
);
```

Comment: You seem to have written the correct verification routine (aside from not using a fixed time equality comparison). What’s your actual question / where are you stuck?

Comment: @bartonjs , I'm stuck at calling the method. The reference that I had was using a user user = getuserdetails sort of code and then calling it in the verifypassword method to compare the salt and hash. That is the part I do not understand. Furthermore, could you elaborate on the fixed time equality comparison?
Is it critical and important for it to be included?

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use Salt in your hash storage, you should keep the salt value for the password input in your database, appended to the hash value or stored in another column like you've done so.

To verify the password, your code needs to query that salt value for the given user, and use that value in the hash digest method the same way as you have used in your password salt+hash calculation, then you make a comparison.

**To summarize:**

1. Generate your random salt value for a new password storage request;
2. Define where you'll want to append your salt value. You can do concatenations such as salt+password, password+salt. The important thing is to generate the hash digest containing as an input your salt and the password, to make more difficult the use of rainbow tables;
3. Store your hash generated with password and salt, and store the salt as well;
4. When your user attempts a login, get that user's salt value in your database, then apply the same hashing method based on his input, concatenating it with your queried salt, the same way as your hash storage method does;
5. If both hash digests are equal, then you can proceed to authentication.

Take a look at this [article](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/) to understand salting better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method for creating and retrieving your hash:

```
        public static byte[] GetHash(string inputString)
        {
            HashAlgorithm algorithm = SHA256.Create();
            return algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
        }

        public static string GetHashString(string inputString)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in GetHash(inputString))
                sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Then, when a user is registered, get the plaintext password and generate the random salt, and you can simply save the password hash like this:

```
      newUser.password = GetHashString(salt + password);
```

Don't forget to also save the salt somewhere in your database as well (I typically save my salt in the same table as the password hash).

Now, when the user wants to login, take their input and search your database for the username that was entered, if you get a result back (there should only be one result assuming that usernames have to be unique and they input a valid username), then get the salt associated with that account and generate the hash again:

```
      string compareHash = GetHashString(salt + password);
```

Now it's just a matter of comparing that calculated hash with the stored hash in the database, if the two match, then log them in!

Comment: Why not just generate a salt for the concatenation of the password and the hash and then compare the salt of the user input and the one in database?